# List of Method Calls During Execution of Java Unit Test

Tags: java, junit, aspectj, call-graph, javaagents

I have a situation where I need to know what methods are being called from a single JUnit test. For example, if I have the following pseudo-code:

```
public class UnitTest {    
  public main() {
    Circle c = new Circle()
    c.getArea()
  }
} 

public class Circle {
  public Circle() {
    ...
  }    
  public getArea() {
    ...
    getRadius()
  }
  private getRadius() {
    ...
  }
}
```

The method calls of the *UnitTest* class follow this order (though for my purposes I don't need to preserve order, or to know of the caller's method):

1. UnitTest.main
2. Circle.Circle
3. Circle.getArea
4. Circle.getRadius

Essentially, I want to know what part of the program is actually being exercised in the JUnit tests. I figure I can dynamically figure this out, but I am having trouble finding a tool or approach. The main problem with some of the tools I have found is that they are often very visual (require user interaction to extract the required data). I am looking for something that gives me just a list of the methods (xml, text, etc...) without the GUI aspect. In the end I am trying to automate this for test suites via a scripting approach.

The approaches I am thinking of using would be either:

- Using a Java Agent to print out the *class.method* at every method call.
- Tracing using Aspects [like this](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/examples-development.html#tracing-using-aspects)

If there is a tool which already does this that would be great. If not, does it seem like I am on track to solve my problem using one of the approaches I've specified.

Any help/suggestions would be appreciated.

**UPDATE-SOLVED**
I decided to use Emma with the following commands to extract the information of method calls (just need to parse report for any method over a 0% coverage):

```
emmarun -r xml                 // To output to XML
  -Dreport.sort=-method        // Sort method coverage in descending order
  -Dverbosity.level=silent     // Minimize script output
  -Dreport.metrics=method:1    // Flag any method with a 0% coverage
  -Dreport.columns=method,name // Only show the method and name columns
  -Dreport.depth=method        // Consider the data of method coverage
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for a "Coverage" tool, such as [Emma](http://emma.sourceforge.net/) or [Cobertura](http://cobertura.github.io/cobertura/)?

Comment: I did consider a coverage tool (at the moment I am looking at Emma trying to figure if I can easily extract the desired information from the reports). I am still trying to find a more simple solution to this problem though. There must be some easy way to extract a method call list of a running program.

Comment: Emma and Cobertura can export the results to XML which will contain the class and method names, or have I misinterpreted your requirements?

Comment: After looking at Emma I am pretty sure I can get all the required information from the XML file.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know which methods are called by your test 
you can use a code coverage tools like [cobertura](http://cobertura.sourceforge.net/) or [emma](http://emma.sourceforge.net/).

Both of them provide a great integration with maven ,ant and eclipse
and can produce a xml or html report.